# UITableView selected rows after editing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, edit, selecteditem, selected

I try to get the selected rows of an UITableView after editing mode ends.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"did end editing");
    NSArray *selectedRows = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSLog(@"%i", selectedRows.count);
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. This method never gets called, when I'm ending editing.

In fact I want the user to be able to select some rows and pass the respective data into a mail.

How do get these cells?! I hope you can help me!

Greetings, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think editing is the thing you want to be looking for.

Editing applies to just one cell at a time. (via [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate))

You probably need to implement your own edit mode and handle keeping track of which cells a user selects to perform an edit on. Then when they say "commit edit" (or w/e language you are using) then perform that edit on those cells.

This might help:

[Edit & delete multiple rows in UITableView simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227168/edit-delete-multiple-rows-in-uitableview-simultaneously)

Comment: I just figured out some way. I'm putting the cells into an array `if(tableView.editing){[array addObject:cell];}` when selecting and delete them when deselecting. I don't know if this is a very charming way... But it works for me :) Thanks for answer, though

Comment: I think that makes a lot of sense. Glad you were able to figure out a way.